# Elasticsearch Completion in middle of the sentence

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

is it possible to perform `Completion` on Elasticsearch and get result even if text is from the middle of input?

For instance:

```
"TitleSuggest" : {
  "type" : "completion",
  "index_analyzer" : "simple",
  "search_analyzer" : "simple",
  "payloads" : true,
  "preserve_position_increments" : false,
  "preserve_separators" : false
}
```

That's my current mapping and my query is

```
{
  "passport": {
    "text": "Industry Overview",
    "completion": {
      "field": "TitleSuggest",
      "fuzzy": {
        "edit_distance": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing is returned, I have documents that contain `Industry Overview` in their input. For instance if I'm looking only for `Industry`:

```
{
  "text" : "Industry",
  "offset" : 0,
  "length" : 8,
  "options" : [{
      "text" : "Airline Industry Sees Recovery in 2014",
      "score" : 16
    }, {
      "text" : "Alcoholic Drinks Industry Overview",
      "score" : 16
    }, {
      "text" : "Challenges in the Pet Care Industry For 2014",
      "score" : 16
    }
  ]
}
```

I can achieve that by using nGrams, but I'd like to get this done using [completion suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me)

So my initial goal would getting this if I type in `Industry Overview`

```
{
  "text" : "Industry Overview",
  "offset" : 0,
  "length" : 8,
  "options" : [{
      "text" : "Alcoholic Drinks Industry Overview",
      "score" : 16
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried using shingle analyzer - that didn't solve the problem and I didn't come up on Google with anything useful.

ES Version : `1.5.1`